# Interpretation of oglmx output (Heteroscedastic Ordered Probit Regression)

Tags: r

I'm running a Heteroscedastic Ordered Probit Regression using "oglmx" but I don't fully understand the output. It gives the Mean Equation and the SD Equation output. I don't understand the difference and how exactly should I interpret the results. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `sdmodel` part is for heteroskedasticity. I recommend you to have a look at [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwilwa3mwffoAhVIqxoKHQ0uA8gQFjAEegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmran.microsoft.com%2Fsnapshot%2F2016-10-12%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Foglmx%2Fvignettes%2FoglmxVignette.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1_xDU15sg8yph0lAonanLb) which explains quite well the different part of an `oglmx` model.

In the `mean` equation, you model the relationship between your covariates and the latent variable y*. If they are not known, you can also estimate the thresholds between the classes. From the paper:

> In homoskedastic models the signs of regression coefficients are informative of the sign of the marginal effects for outcomes at the extreme of the distribution, but not for intermediate outcomes. In contrast in a heteroskedastic model the sign of a variable's coefficient(s) is on its own uninformative on the sign of any marginal effect when it enters the equation for the variance.

[image]

`sigma` is the error term. You can assume it is iid, in which case you are in homoskedastic setting. Or you can assume it depends, in some ways, of some covariates. `sdequation` is meant to modelize the relationship between these individual specific characteristics *Z* and the error term `sigma`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have used the same paper for running the regressions. I do understand that sdequation models the heteroscedastic error term, however, I'm still not sure which of the two models( meanmodel or sdmodel) should I use for the interpretation of my coefficients as in the significance and sign? Because according to my knowledge if the threshold values are known the coefficients can be interpreted in the same way as the normal OLS coeffcients and marginal effects do not really need to calculated.